# .htaccess error 500 or access forbidden

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<Files.htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./redirect.php?url_token=$1
```

My script's logic:

My script is not in the root of the website, it's in a folder (ex: www.mywebsite.com/script/). I have the .htaccess file in this folder.

The PHP script gets that url_token value and processes it, it is working well, i've tested it.

But when I use this .htaccess file and I try to access an URL like `www.mywebsite.com/script/fa34d` where `fa34d` is a random generated code, I get:

> Error 500 on XAMPP and Access Forbidden on another online host.

What can be the problem?

I've already spent more time with this than the rest of the script.

Comment: `<Files.htaccess>` missing a space and `RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./redirect.php?url_token=$1` you need to remove the `.` from `./`

Comment: If you get a 500, you need to _look in your Apache error log_ to find out what the cause of the error was. That will point you toward a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely creating a loop or you're redirecting to a file outside of your document root. If the folder accessed as the root is that same as what displays as `www.mywebsite.com` then you can set `RewriteBase /` in your access file. Remember all `.htaccess` files work together and also work with your `VirtualHosts` directives on the server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /redirect.php?url_token=$1
```

Comment: @Prix yeah, I wrote that before it occurred to me that they probably don't want to rewrite all of the other files that exist.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add this line to hide your directory from http request in your .htaccess file

Options -Indexes

Enjoy!!